# check if all loop items have been skipped

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to check if all loop items from a previous step have been skipped?
I want to download the latest files from the GitHub API and compare them to the templated ones. Only the files that have changed will be commited as blobs. Based on the `skipped` property, I can check what needs to be included in the tree.
But how can I skip the `Create tree` action when all items in `blobs` have been skipped?
`when: "not skipped(blobs)"` in `Create tree` only for illustration purposes.

```yaml
- name: Download current files
  uri:
    url: https://github.com/api/v3/repos{{ repository.path }}/contents{{ item.path }}
    user: "{{ API_USER }}"
    password: "{{ API_TOKEN }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: [ 200, 404 ]
  register: current_files
  loop:
    - {path: "/.github/workflows/build.yml"}
    - {path: "/.github/workflows/deploy-dev.yml"}
    - {path: "/.github/workflows/deploy-int.yml"}
    - {path: "/.github/workflows/deploy-prod.yml"}

- name: Commit file blob
  uri:
    url: https://github.com/api/v3/repos{{ repository.path }}/git/blobs
    method: "POST"
    user: "{{ API_USER }}"
    password: "{{ API_TOKEN }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
    status_code: [200, 201]
    body: |
      {
        "encoding": "base64",
        "content": "{{ lookup('template', item.src) | b64encode }}",
      }
  vars:
    target_group: "{{ item.target_group }}"
    service_deployment_env: "{{ item.service_deployment_env }}"
  when: "(lookup('template', item.src) | b64encode) != current_files['results'][index]['json']['content'].replace('\n', '')"
  register: blobs
  loop:
    - { src: 'build.yml.jinja2', dest: '.github/workflows/build.yml', service_deployment_env: '' }
    - { src: 'deploy.yml.jinja2', dest: '.github/workflows/deploy-dev.yml', service_deployment_env: 'dev' }
    - { src: 'deploy.yml.jinja2', dest: '.github/workflows/deploy-int.yml', service_deployment_env: 'int' }
    - { src: 'deploy.yml.jinja2', dest: '.github/workflows/deploy-prod.yml', service_deployment_env: 'prod' }
  loop_control:
    index_var: index

- name: Create tree
  uri:
    url: https://github.com/api/v3/repos{{ repository.path }}/git/trees
    method: "POST"
    user: "{{ API_USER }}"
    password: "{{ API_TOKEN }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: json
    status_code: [200, 201]
    body: "{{ lookup('template', 'create_tree_body.json.jinja2') }}"
  when: "not skipped(blobs)" # HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE??
  register: tree
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok... this was too easy. Apparently, ansible resolves the `blobs` list by itself, so simply using

```
when: "blobs is not skipped"
```

works just fine.